# Ember Use Mixin OR Service for shared data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using Ember 2 in my app.

My question is for sharing data between routes (not simple params which we can do using Query/Path params, but slightly larger data like object info)

What is the best way to do the same; Mixin OR Service ?
I want singleton shared instance. I know Ember Service is by default singleton. But is there some way by which we can get singleton shared object using Ember Mixin ?

Answer (score 1):

A Service is what you need, not a mixin!

You should never have an instance of an mixin, because you only should use them to mix them into your actual objects.

Comment: But isn't the purpose of a service for a broader scope like application-wide sharing like say session info? Here I want shared info between 3-4 route objects. So what is more suitable for this ?

Comment: `So what is more suitable for this?` a service injected into those 3-4 routes @testndtv